# Track http requests of an iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, httpwebrequest

Is it possible to list/track http requests made by an iframe in a webpage? Can we do this using javascript in the parent DOM of the iframe?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: How did you go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the iframe tells you that it is requesting data, you can't do this. A javascript function in the document loaded in the iframe could do this.

You can check what document the iframe is pointing to, but if you are opening any random page if the iframe, you cannot track what all requests it is making.

Comment: if JS is in the same DOM, is it possible?

Comment: What if I do not have an iframe, I just have a URL and I want to track the http requests generated from this URL.

Comment: What do you mean by JS is in the same DOM? Do you mean content of the iframe comes from your site?

Comment: My use case is just to track httprequests generated by a URL but I want to do this using JS

Answer (score 2):

just do that to got all request that fired from page include iframe `href` . yes not what you search for but something

```js
window.performance.getEntries().map(e => e.name )
```

you can filter the `initiator` if you like your

Comment: Although helpful, I still cannot see some of the requests displayed on the network log. Don't know what kind of filtering the browser does, but it certainly won't return all of the  iframe requests.